# Pdfmake duplicate JSON Object content

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object, pdfmake

I've got a `pdfmake` script that generates a `pdf` correctly from dynamic elements, as I need.

However, I need to `duplicate` my whole content to make a `copy` of my pages in the final PDF.

The dynamic content is stored in the `JSON object` "content".

I tried to do the following : `content = content+content` but my pdf return something like : `[object Object][object Object]`

Using the [pdkmake playground](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html), I noticed that this command is working sometimes, as you can see with this following script :

```
content= [
        'this text will be duplicated..or not  '
    ];

var dd = {
    content: content+content
    }
```

But as soon as the `JSON object` is a bit more complex, it will fail :

```
content= [
    {
       text: 'this text will be duplicated..or not  ',
       pageBreak: 'after',
    }
    ];

var dd = {
    content: content+content
    }
```

So, i've tried to use `content = $.merge( content, content )`. It seems to copy some intels, but when generating the PDF, the result is a blank page, where the text is not showing :

```
content= [
    {
       text: 'this text will be duplicated..or not  ',
       pageBreak: 'after',
    }
    ];

content = $.merge( content, content );
var dd = {
    content: content
    }
```

A solution would be to call again my script that generates the dynamic JSON Object, but it wouldn't really be "clean" as I would like.

Can you please figure out why it isn't working and explain to me what the proper way to combine two objects?

For me, the problem is that `content` is looking something like `content = [{1},{2},{3}]` and that when i do `content=content+content` it keeps the `[]` and the result is something like : `content = [[{1},{2},{3}],[{1},{2},{3}]]` instead of `content = [[{1},{2},{3},{1},{2},{3}]]`. Am I correct ?

Sorry if I'm not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
var content = [
        'My text'
    ];

var dd = {
    content:[content, {text:"", pageBreak: "after"}, content] //Break the page and repeat the content in next page
}
```